# How can I increase the tasks.max for debezium sql connnector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I tried setting the configuration for debezium MySQL connector for the property
'tasks.max=50'

But the connector in logs shows error as below:
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only a single connector task may be started'

I am using MSK Connector with debezium custom plugin and Debezium version 1.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible.

The database bin log must be read sequentially by only one task.

Run multiple connectors for different tables if you want to distribute workload

Comment: Are you sure, can you share official doc regarding this ?

Comment: @RajSaraogi Is the error not documentation enough? _"The MySQL connector always uses a single task"_ - [mysql connect config docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.8/connectors/mysql.html)

Comment: as a developer I need to confirm the error from original docs to reverify that there is no configuration error from my side. Thanks for the answer link and one suggestion next time if you could add links in the answer itself, that will make it more fruitful.